# Magento module including

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, модули

Пробую создать модуль для Magento. Административную часть уже сделала. Теперь мне надо, чтобы модуль работал на всех страницах в frontend, но я не знаю,

как это реализовать.

Comment: А в чем затруднения?

Comment: я  новичок  в magento и не могу  придумать  способ , чтоб  модуль работал  был включен на всех страницах. Думала  , что  есть таблица  , где надо просто  добавить  id  своего модуля или что -то вроде этого.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно уточнить что именно должно работать на всех страницах, если модуль включен и админка работает значит он активен, возможно нужен доступ к контроллеру, блоку, хелперу что именно должно быть во фронте?, т.к. по сути он и так работает на всех страницах, важны детали.